# IdeaVim in Pycharm randomly terminates search popup

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I use IdeaVim in PyCharm Community Edition with IdeaVim in Ubuntu 14.04. There are several commands that summon a search popup, e.g. 'Navigate File...', 'Find Action...', etc. For some reason, these popups randomly close after typing a few characters (usually 4?). Uninstalling IdeaVim seems to prevent the problem from happening, but I would rather not use PyCharm without Vim keybindings. Please advise on the best solution to this issue.

Comment: Make sure use IdeaVim 0.48 or higher.

Comment: I am currently using version 0.48.

Comment: i wonder if the option "Hide navigation popups on focus loss" might help you though it sounds different from the cause of your issue

Comment: The problem is difficult to reproduce predictably. I haven't had much of an opportunity to work in PyCharm recently, but I am starting a new Python project. If disabling that option makes the problem go away, I will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have now been using PyCharm for some time with "Hide navigation popups on focus loss" turned off, as suggested by dtc. So far, this seems to solve the problem. I think the issue was that I use i3 windows tiling manager and I use the "focus follows mouse" setting. This was probably causing the search popup to become unfocused and to subsequently close.